# How can I make Deja Dup use AES 256 as the encryption algorithm?

Tags: security, backup, encryption, deja-dup, gnupg

I'm using Deja Dup on Oneiric Ocelot.

How can I make it use AES 256 as the algorithm for encryption?

Or for that matter, how can I control which encryption algorithm is used?

Deja Dup uses duplicity which in turn uses GnuPG. GnuPG uses CAST5 by default, but it also supports AES-256. However, I have no idea what parameters Deja Dup passes to duplicity and what parameters duplicity passes to GnuPG. So... how can I control which algorithm is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a bit late but if you put `s2k-cipher-algo AES256` in ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf then all your deja-dup backups will be encrypted with AES256.  The only downside  to this is that if you didn't have this option enabled from the first backup, all your other backups become pointless at that point because you'll need to delete them all and start over.  So before you set the option please pick your backups for files that need to be kept.

Comment: Thanks, anyway, I started using duplicity directly. Much more control and I know what's going on.

Comment: Not sure this is accurate - from the manual, s2k-cipher-algo is used for encrypting private keys, whereas just plain "cipher-algo" determines the  symmetric algorithm. (and the default is Blowfish) https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/r1434.html

Answer (score 1):

Per Michael Terry, "Deja Dup uses the default in GnuPG, which as of this writing is CAST5. This can't be changed via Deja Dup."

https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/176785

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
duplicity [source] [destination] --gpg-options '--cipher-algo AES256'
```

in `htop` you can confirm that gpg is using `AES256`

But according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard)  "*By default, GnuPG uses the AES symmetrical algorithm since version 2.1*"