# Automated Backups + Encryption

Tags: backup, encryption, archive

I have set up my Ubuntu 12.04LTS machine as a Subversion server. I have a cloud-based backup system which routinely backs up files of mine (CrashPlan) to an online server, as well as to a backup NAS on my local network.

I am skeptical of the security any of these solutions really provides, so the bulk of my work is stored in a secure TrueCrypt partition with multiple independent keys. I back it up automatically, but it cannot be backed up while in use, so I would have to endure some downtime during each backup, which is not acceptable in this case.

I am looking for a way, in Ubuntu, to have certain folders of mine backed up automatically as a single archived file (ie: tar.bz2, or similar), and heavily encrypted either via a passphrase, or a passphrase-protected private key, using at least AES256.

Are there any straightforward, UI-based backup applications for Ubuntu that are "tried and true", and can schedule automatic, "hot" backups of folders to another location on my local machine, and automatically encrypt them? The plan would be to add this backup destination to the list of folders my cloud backup system monitors. This way, the files themselves are already encrypted such that I possess the only key, in case the cloud backup company is compromised.

I know I could write some cron jobs and shell scripts to accomplish this easily enough, but time does not permit right now to test the scripts extensively enough to guarantee that they are fail safe.

Thank you.

Comment: The default back up tool, duplicity, will do this. See http://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/

Comment: Agreed, it covers most of my use case, but I have no idea what type of encryption it uses, how secure it is, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other requirements needed to enable AES256 were found here:

[How can I make Deja Dup use AES 256 as the encryption algorithm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73405/how-can-i-make-deja-dup-use-aes-256-as-the-encryption-algorithm)