# Deja Dup Backup: Limit Drive Space Usage and Force Full Backups Only

Tags: 12.04, backup, disk-usage, deja-dup

Good day,

I have configured Deja Dup to backup my home folder and a couple other locations to a folder on a spare drive of mine, `/media/backupDrive/myBackups`. I have made some minor changes to GnuPG, as noted in another post ([Automated Backups + Encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350870/automated-backups-encryption)) so that it uses AES256 for encryption.

I have two problems with Deja Dup though:

1. It seems that it performs an initial full backup, and then differential backups afterwards. I don't see any way to control the backup types with finer granularity. Since It's backing up large (50GB+) encrypted binary archives, I don't want it doing differential backups. I just want it to do FULL/COMPLETE backups each time, and never attempt differential or incremental backups. Is this possible?
2. It also seems that backups will continue each week until the drive runs out of space, at which point Deja Dup will supposedly delete the oldest backups to make room for new backups. Is there a way to cap how many GB in size the backup folder can be, rather than allowing Deja Dup to fill up the entire drive? I guess I could just re-partition the drive mounted at `/media/backupDrive`, but I'd like to avoid that at the moment if I can.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can do this, but only on Deja Dup 24 or higher.  Which means using Ubuntu 12.10 or higher.  There is no backport to 12.04 LTS right now.

To make Deja Dup 24 always do full backups, run the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.DejaDup full-backup-period 1
```

2) Nope!  :-/